# MAX on group returns multiple values with same date but different times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, max

I have followed many of the excellent pieces of advise on this site about selecting the MAX from a group of rows.

I have a history file and I only want the top date and comments for each project number. I am creating a derived table in a Boxi universe from this information. It all goes pretty well but if there are two entries for the same day but with different times they are both returned. This duplicates that entry on the subsequent report. Is there some way to make the MAX command go down to the time level of the date field?

Database is SQL Server 2005

-------------Sql used for derived table

```
Select
   Projectno, Comment, CreatedOn
from 
   ReportHistory
Where
   ReportHistory.ItemName=('ProjectCode1')
and
   CreatedOn in(Select max(CreatedOn) FROM ReportHistory group by Projectno)
```

-------------------Example database

```
Projectno     Comment             Created on

1             Started             2013-01-04 11:04:00
2             Late                2013-01-06 11:22:00
3             Late                2013-01-07 11:06:00
1             On Time             2013-01-08 11:01:00   *these two both get selected*
1             Late                2013-01-08 12:05:00   *these two both get selected*
3             Back on schedule    2013-01-08 14:20:00
2             Still overdue       2013-01-09 09:01:00
```

Answer (score 1):

`MAX` on a `DATETIME` data type do obviously take the time into account, that is not what's wrong with your query. The problem is that you are not ensuring that the max value for `CreatedOn` is for the correct `ProjectNo`. You could use analytical functions for this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  Projectno, 
            Comment, 
            CreatedOn,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProjectNo ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC) RN
    FROM ReportHistory
    WHERE ReportHistory.ItemName = 'ProjectCode1'
)
SELECT Projectno, Comment, CreatedOn
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: I tried running the original query and the CTE and for me, using SQL2008 and the sample data from the original post, both queries yield the same result. The subquery **SELECT MAX(CreatedOn) FROM ReportHistory GROUP BY Projectno** does indeed return the correct 3 rows and from what I can see the original query should work.

Comment: @jpw It will return the same results for the data posted, but op is most likely using a lot more data. If there is a row for a projectno that was created on the same date that the max date created of another projectno, then the original query will return wrong results

Answer (score 0):

Query if there are no same projectno with the same date:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39996/11)**

```
SELECT h.Projectno,
       h.Comment,
       h.[Created on]
FROM ReportHistory h
WHERE h.[Created on] =(Select max(h2.[Created on])
                       FROM ReportHistory h2 
                       WHERE h2.Projectno = h.Projectno )
ORDER BY h.Projectno
```

Result:

```
| PROJECTNO |          COMMENT |                     CREATED ON |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |             Late | January, 08 2013 12:05:00+0000 |
|         2 |    Still overdue | January, 09 2013 09:01:00+0000 |
|         3 | Back on schedule | January, 08 2013 14:20:00+0000 |
```

Query if there are same projectno with the same date:

```
SELECT h.Projectno,
       MAX(h.Comment) AS Comment,
       h.[Created on]
FROM ReportHistory h
WHERE h.[Created on] =(Select max(h2.[Created on])
                       FROM ReportHistory h2 
                       WHERE h2.Projectno = h.Projectno )
GROUP BY h.Projectno,
       h.[Created on]
ORDER BY h.Projectno
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you receive copies when dates at different projects are identical.

For eg. add in your data (4, 'On Time', '2013-01-08 11:01:00')
                                                                                                           Then result will be [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0e727/1/0)

But you need this result [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0e727/2/0)

```
SELECT *
FROM ReportHistory t
WHERE t.ItemName=('ProjectCode1')
  AND EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM ReportHistory                              
              WHERE projectNo = t.projectNo
              GROUP BY projectNo
              HAVING MAX(CreatedOn) = t.CreatedOn
              )
```